# 2条件のグループ別の平均値

Tags: r, tidyverse

以下のデータフレームに対してgroup1とgroup2それぞれの要約統計量（平均、最大値、最小値など）を出力したいです。ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

例）
MenのAグループの平均値＝
MenのBグループの平均値＝
WomenのAグループの平均値＝
WomenのBグループの平均値＝

```
df <- data.frame(age=1:100, group1=c(rep("Men", 50), rep("Women",50)), group2=c(rep("A", 25), rep("B",25),rep("C",25),rep("D",25)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))

df %>% split(list(.$group1, .$group2)) %>% Filter(function(x) nrow(x) > 0, .) %>% map(~ summary(.$age))
```